# Codeigniter Image Manipulation library behaving strangely

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-processing

I am trying to resize images using image_lib library class of CodeIgniter but it's giving me errors, the problem is the process gets stopped at random file and gives me the same error. What I mean is sometimes it would process 14 files and gives the error on 15th file, sometimes it would do it on 10th file etc..

*All the files are either jpg or png. The code haven't got far enough to encounter any png file yet, so that's not the problem I think.*

CODE:

```
    /* $directory_path is absolute server path */

    function _thumbnails ( $directory_path )
    {

        $thumbnails = $directory_path .  '\\thumbnails';

        $this->load->helper ( 'directory' );
        $temp [ 'paths' ] = directory_map (  $directory_path, 1  );

        if (  ! $temp [ 'paths' ]  ){return FALSE;}

        if ( ! mkdir ( $thumbnails, 0700 )  ){return FALSE;}


        /* image_lib configs*/
        $config [ 'image_library' ] = 'GD2';
        $config [ 'width' ] = 300;
        $config [ 'height' ] = 300;

        this->load->library ( 'image_lib' );


        foreach ( $temp [ 'paths' ] as $value ) 
        {
            $config [ 'source_image' ] = $directory_path . '\\' . $value;
            $config [ 'new_image' ] = $thumbnails . '\\' . $value;

            if ( is_dir ( $config [ 'source_image' ] ) ){continue;}

            $this->image_lib->clear (  );

            $this->image_lib->initialize ( $config );

            if ( ! $this->image_lib->resize (  )  )
            {
                $this->_error_data (  $this->image_lib->display_errors (  )  ); // Last line of error comes from here.
                return FALSE;
            }
        }

        chmod ( $thumbnails, 0755 ) ;

        return TRUE;
    }
```

**ERRORS :**

```
<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  getimagesize(E:/APACHE/htdocs/Chris/thumbnails): failed to open stream: Permission denied</p>
<p>Filename: libraries/Image_lib.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 1637</p>

Your server does not support the GD function required to process this type of image
```

> **EDIT 1:** Could it be that the function encounters a sub directory in the array returned by directory_map() ?
>
> **EDIT 2:** Although the above fix took me further in the processing and
>   code was able to process more files then ever, but I still got the
>   error.

**ERROR**

```
Your server does not support the GD function required to process this type of image.

JPG images are not supported.
```

> **EDIT 3:** What does `Message:  getimagesize(E:/APACHE/htdocs/Chris/thumbnails): failed to open stream: Permission denied` means ? Does it means the function encountered thumbnail directory ?
>
> Changed the code a bit and put `directory_map();` above `mkdir();` **Didn't work :(**

Now the only error I am getting is this : `Your server does not support the GD function required to process this type of image. JPG images are not supported.`

**Why JPG images are not supported when it actually did process other jpg ? I changed the images but still the error remains.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the error `Your server does not support the GD function required to process this type of image. JPG images are not supported.` after actually processing some files gives a wrong impression, that the code had some problems, but in the situation it's advisable to look at if the image library is installed and enabled.

It turned out that the problem was with the gd2 library not being enabled in the php.ini

Just uncomment `;extension=php_gd2.dll` in your php.ini to enable the gd2 library.